# XML::Compile::SOAP and calling a web service with WSDL

Tags: perl, soap-client

I'm having a tough time making a SOAP call to a webservice, the WSDL looks something like this:

```
<wsdl:definitions name="Service" targetNamespace="/Service/">
    <wsdl:types>
        <xsd:schema targetNamespace="/#/">
        <xsd:element name="authToken">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="username" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="password" type="xsd:string"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
           </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="fault">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="faultType">
                        <xsd:simpleType>
                            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                <xsd:enumeration value="REQUIRED"/>
                                <xsd:enumeration value="INVALID"/>
                           </xsd:restriction>
                        </xsd:simpleType>
                   </xsd:element>
                   <xsd:element name="faultData" type="xsd:string"/>
               </xsd:sequence>
           </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:simpleType name="param1">
            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:int"/>
        </xsd:simpleType>
        <xsd:simpleType name="param2">
            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:int"/>
        </xsd:simpleType>
        <xsd:simpleType name="param3">
            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:int"/>
        </xsd:simpleType>
        <xsd:element name="Add">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element ref="tns:authToken"/>
                        <xsd:element name="param1" type="tns:param1"/>
                       <xsd:element name="param2" type="tns:param2"/>
                       <xsd:element name="param3" type="tns:param3"/>
                        <xsd:choice>
                            <xsd:element name="Name">
                                <xsd:complexType>
                                    <xsd:sequence>
                                        <xsd:element name="first" type="tns:namefirst"/>
                                        <xsd:element name="last" type="tns:namelast"/>
                                    </xsd:sequence>
                                </xsd:complexType>
                            </xsd:element>
....
```

Then using XML:Compile, I do the following

```
use XML::Compile::WSDL11;
use XML::Compile::SOAP11;
use XML::Compile::Transport::SOAPHTTP;
my $wsdlXml = XML::LibXML->new->parse_file("pathtowsdl");
my $wsdl = XML::Compile::WSDL11->new($wsdlXml);
my $call = $wsdl->compileClient('Add');
my %param = ('authToken'    =>  {
                    'username'  =>  'xxx',
                    'password'  =>  'xxxx',
                    },
             'param1'   =>  'xxx',
             'param2'   =>  'xxxx',
             'param3'   =>  'xxxx',
             'Name'     =>  {
                'first' =>  'xxx',
                'last'  =>  'xxx',
              });
my ($response, $trace) = $call->(\%params);
```

I get a fault from the above:

Unmarshalling Error: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"authToken")

If I take out "authToken" then I'll get the local error of "error: required value for element `authToken' missing".

I assume my params structure is wrong but I'm not sure what it should be. Any ideas?

TIA

Comment: Have you tried tracing, e.g. `use SOAP::Lite +trace => 'debug'`?

Comment: The trace is where the "unmarshalling error...." comes up (which of course doesn't help too much :)

Comment: I think you are missing some namespace declarations in your WSDL xml. Is there anything you've cut out from the top of the file?

I'd try it with the following instead of your first line:

    `<wsdl:definitions name="Service" targetNamespace="/Service/" 
      xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
      xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" >`

However it looks like you'll need a declaration for xmlns:tns as well.